# Excel Ribbon Greyed Out Issue During Swift Communication Data Transfer

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am encountering a peculiar problem in Excel where the ribbon becomes greyed out intermittently when clicking continuously on the excel while data is being loaded from Swift communication. This issue seems to occur during the data retrieval process, and I'm struggling to pinpoint the root cause.

Switching my attention from Excel to another application and then refocusing on Excel resolves this issue.

I am seeking guidance on troubleshooting and resolving this issue. Has anyone experienced a similar problem or have insights into potential causes and solutions?

before switching focus

[image: 1]

after refocus

[image: 2]

I've attempted to address this by using AppActivate "Microsoft Excel" and introducing a time delay, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be the solution.